# How to run modal from Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a modal and i want run it from code behind my modal:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div dir="rtl" id="mymodal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalRapidAddLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalRapidAddLabel">Edit Brand</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Enter New Name</p>
            <div class="control-group">

                <div class="controls">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">cancel</button>

        </div>
    </div></ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my Code Behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "none","<script>$('#mymodal').modal('show');</script>", false);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mymodal", "$('#mymodal').modal();", true);
```

every where i shearched this code must run the modal but this don't worked for me why?

Comment: See if you are getting any error on client side? does your javascript code exectutes

Comment: any error but when i code behind runned any thing doesent happend

Comment: is it because your modal is inside an update panel?

Comment: i try it without update panelbut it;s not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, create an `asp button`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Search" ID="cmdSearch" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your code behind:

```
        protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "",
                "$('#mymodal').modal('show');", true);
    }
```